# SSL https (http secure) sites won't display is client or server side?

Tags: firefox, arch-linux, ssl, security-warning

Oddly, python.org has suddenly become unreachable for me through the Archlinux repo version of Firefox (v27 and v28.0 update):

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> An error occurred during a connection to www.python.org. The OCSP
>   response is not yet valid (contains a date in the future).
>
> (Error code: sec_error_ocsp_future_response)
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
>   Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this
>   broken site.

I've read [Mozilla](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/994914?esab=a&s=sec_error_ocsp_future_response&r=1&as=s) [site](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-ssl-fix-cannot-connect-securely-error?esab=a&s=security+oscp+get+enabled&r=1&as=s) recommends:

1. Clear cache (or reload not from cache) (ok)
2. Check your computer's time settings (ok)
3. Check `about:config` settings:

   - `security.OCSP.enabled = 1`  (ok)
   - `security.enable_ssl` & `security.enable_tls` 
     (I think this last one is outdated, because my version reads `security.[some protocol].enable`)
4. Check proxy settings (don't have one)
5. If you're having trouble with one site, use this [checker](http://weblogin.bu.edu/troubleshooting?cmd=ssl) (passed)

With 65 settings in `about:config` with the term 'security', I don't even know where to begin turning things on and off. Like what is `security.OSCP.GET.enabled=false` setting? Sounds like it should be on, but its off. Although I don't have any trouble with logging into my bank's web site.

All points point to python.org having the trouble, but can I be sure? And why the heck is python.org a secure site anyway?

Comment: I am going to guess the reason you can't connect  is because the website revoked it's ssl certificate.  It's possible this is on purpose

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for your input. While that may be true, I found something on the [Arch site](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179329) reminding me of a stupid [Arch-thingy](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time#UTC_in_Windows). The clock was lagging by five hours but the date was correct (its a laptop and happens more than I wish). After I followed these page steps to update my system's time using `date` instead of `timedatectl` python.org is again visible.  Despite this discrepancy, why in the world can I log into my bank, but not python.org?? Talk about paranoid!

Comment: SSL is complicated.  We would need to know what the bank website does and does not support.  Its also a separate question.  If your wondering OSCP is connected to checking the status of the certification chain.

Comment: @xtian try to use this site to test the website you are talking about. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=jbclick.jaxbchfl.net

Comment: @Ramhound are you sure this is a SSL issue and not a TLS issue? I know sometime in 2014 the POODLE attack came out and because of that sites tried to stop using SSL.

Comment: @cokedude - TLS is SSL, its the samething they just changed the name.

Comment: Wow. This is a zombie-post. Hahah. I haven't noticed this problem recently, and SSL is outside my bailiwick. 

So, someone (@Ramhound ?) wants to upvote the answer, I'll mark it answered and put it to bed. (>_<)

Comment: @xtian - I have not really said anything with enough quality to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Before anyone blindly turns off that warning by disabling OCSP, double-check that it's really not a client issue. Turning off warning messages is something you **only** do if you have a VERY GOOD reason and you know what you're doing - or if you are the White House, where "[the alarm system had been switched off due to complaints from staff that it was too noisy](http://www.thetimes.co.uk/tto/news/world/americas/article4222774.ece)". However, if you take this issue seriously, you don't do that.

It might simply be that the system clock is slow, because the error message says "contains a date in the future". And it is much more likely that your computer's date/time is incorrect rather than that of the server (that could affect hundreds of clients).

Open a terminal and check your time:

```
$ date
```

Restart your NTP service to correct it:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ntpd && echo OK
```

If you don't have the NTP service installed ("not-found" error), install it:

```
$ sudo pacman -S ntp
```

Also, make sure it's enabled

```
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled ntpd || sudo systemctl enable ntpd
```

With NTP installed and enabled, restart it, give it a couple of seconds to fetch the time and then check the time:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart ntpd && sleep 30 && date
```

Then try accessing the website again.

Depending on what desktop environment you use, you may be able to use graphical tools instead of those commands.

---

And for those who have "fixed" this issue by disabling every security feature until it worked: Please re-enable whatever you have disabled. If you've disabled OCSP, enable it again. Those features are there for a reason.

Comment: **As I mentioned in April of '15, this isn't my area of expertise. If future readers find this answer useful, please vote it up so I can mark it as the Correct Answer!**

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to disable OCSP. This should really only be done if you travel a lot and can't keep your time and date accurate.

Open about:config and search for **ocsp**.

This seems to be the important one.

**security.ssl.enable_ocsp_stapling;false**

---

- **security.OCSP.enabled;0**
- **services.sync.prefs.sync.security.OCSP.enabled;false**
- **services.sync.prefs.sync.security.OCSP.require;false**

http://www.pixhost.org/show/1355/26717638_ocsp.jpg